# How to get root path asp.net site but exe path in windows app?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm making a nuget library that reads from file. 
I would like to, by default read the file from:

- main site's path if the package is added to web application
- main app path (where the exe is) is this is added to Windows application.

I don't want to depend on any System.Web.* because requiring System.Web in windows application would be, at least, strange.

Answer (score 1):

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is what you looking for. Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.basedirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Oh gracias. Documentation suggested that it should be "bin" in website path but it is not, and this is the correct answer. I hope that this question stays on stack so formed this way because when I googled I didn't find the answer nor the question asked in that form. Thanks.